# NameError: name 'res' is not defined

Tags: python

### I get the following error:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
81     writer.save()
82
---> 83 write_excel(res)
84

NameError: name 'res' is not defined

Could you please help? :)

```
def read_merge(file):
    """" read files and merge the data """
    
    username = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter = ';')
    merged_output = pd.read_excel('file-1.xlsx')
    merged_output = pd.merge(merged_output, username, how='left', left_on=['h'], right_on=['h2'])
    merged_output = merged_output.drop(columns=['h2'])
    return(merged_output)


def remove_string(merged_output):
    """" remove rows containing strings from list_string """
    
    list_string = ["obj-1", "obj-2"]
    res = merged_output[~merged_output['Rule'].isin(list_string)]
    return res


def add_agg_columns(res):
    """"aggregate columns"""
    
    res = res.groupby('Entity_Name').agg({'Rule': ', '.join, 
                                          'Name':'first',
                                          'Area': 'first',
                                          'Summary': 'first'}).reset_index()
    
                     
def write_excel(res):
    """"Write Excel document"""
    
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\PATH\output.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')  
    workbook=writer.book
    worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet('SHEET')
    writer.sheets['SHEET'] = worksheet
    res.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='SHEET', startcol = 0, startrow = 0)
    
    
    writer.save()
    
write_excel(res)
```

Comment: You've defined functions without using them. `def read_merge(file):` doesn't automatically call the function with the file you want. `return(merged_output)` doesn't automatically feed it to `remove_string(merged_output)`.

Comment: You have defined 'res' within your def items however if you see the indentations you are using it outside of it in the last line. That is why the system throws an error stating that 'res' is not defined.If you want to continue using it that way, you need to declare it globally at the very beginning of the code before you start using it.

Answer (score 2):

The last line of code `write_excel(res)` references variable `res` which is not defined in your code.

The error message `NameError: name 'res' is not defined` should give you some clue at to what is going on

Answer (score 0):

you first need to initialize the variable so called 'res'. you can do this by putting res = 0..

Comment: This won't help a lot. `res.to_excel` will fail if `res` is 0.